# Map service created correctly but is inaccessible from the Flex API

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I created a map service from a mxd document. When I try to display to it through the Flex API:
`<esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer url="http://arcgisServerIP:8399/arcgis/rest/services/myService/MapServer" />`
I get the following response from the server: 
`{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Service 'myService' of type 'MapServer' does not exist or is inaccessible.","details":[]}}`

Does anybody have a solution?

Regards.

Comment: [`404`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) quite literally means the file or resource is just not there.

Comment: How do you know it has been created correctly? Is it accessible in the browser at the REST end point? Did you clear the rest cache?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Thank you. It was the cache that wasn't cleared. I missed that step :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether the services is available via the REST endpoint in the browser. You might need to clear the REST cache before you see it.

Comment: As @DevdattaTengshe mentioned in its comment. I didn't clear the rest cache of the server. That was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to paste your URL in a regular ol' web browswer and get *something*. My advice is to get your URL working in your browser, first, then transfer the working URL to your Flex code.

Either 1) your URL isn't formatted correctly and/or does not correspond to however you built your server/service, 2) your ArcGIS Server instance may not publishing anything in the web scope (i.e. it's not online), or 3) ?

There's not much here to work with beyond the [404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).